# split rows by condition in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table containing 3 columns, one of them 
contains a key:value list of different lengths. 
I wish to rearrange the table such that each row will have only one key, conditioned on the value

for example, suppose that I wish to get all rows for whom the value is <= 2 so that each key is on its own row:\

```
input_tbl <-
data.table::data.table(a=c("AA"),b=c("{\"ha:llo\":1,\"wor:ld\":2,\"doog:bye\":3}"),
c=c(1))
```

the wanted table then should be

```
tbl_output <- data.table::data.table(a=c("AA",
"AA"),b=c("ha:llo","wor:ld"), c=c(1,1), s=c(1,2))
```

I had tried the following function:

```
data_table_clean <- function(dt){

  dt[ ,"b" := data.table::tstrsplit(b, ',', fixed = T),by=c(a, c)]
  dt[,c('b', 's'):= data.table::tstrsplit(b, ':', fixed=TRUE)]
    return(dt[s <=2,])

}
```

this produces the following error

> "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found"

Any suggestions are welcome, off course.

The keys are actually of the form :

```
input2_tbl <-
data.table::data.table(a=c("AA"),b=c("{\"99:1d:3u:7y:89:67\":1,\"99:1D:34:YY:T6:Y6\":2,\"ll:5Y:UY:56:R5:R6\":3}"),
c=c(1))
```

and accordingly the output table should be:

```
 tbl2_output <- data.table::data.table(a=c("AA",
 "AA"),b=c(""99:1d:3u:7y:89:67","99:1D:34:YY:T6:Y6"), 
    c=c(1,1), s=c(1,2))
```

Thank you!

### update

```
data_table_clean <- function(dt){



  res <- dt[, data.table::tstrsplit(unlist(strsplit(gsub('[{}"]', '', b),',', fixed=TRUE)), ":(?=[^:]+$)", perl=TRUE),
                     by = .(a, c)][V2 > -100]

  data.table::setnames(res, 3:4, c("b", "s"))
  res
}
```

when running this I get the following error:

> Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: You've made a typo there. Either use `c("a", "c")`, or `"a,c"` or `.(a, c)` or `list(a, c)`, but not their combinations. Also, your function isn't doing what you think it's doing. I would go step by step and see what's the result.

Comment: Your function is working for me `data_table_clean(input2_tbl)
#    a c                 b s
#1: AA 1 99:1d:3u:7y:89:67 1
#2: AA 1 99:1D:34:YY:T6:Y6 2
#3: AA 1 ll:5Y:UY:56:R5:R6 3`  I am using `data.table_1.9.6`

Comment: Why don't you just put `library(data.table)` at the top and get rid of all those `data.table::` references.

Comment: this is not the problem, (I'm trying to avoid environment dependency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to extract the characters that we need in the final output.  We use `str_extract` to do that after grouping by 'a', 'c'.  The output is a `list`, which we `unlist`, get the non-numeric and numeric into two columns and then subset the rows with the condition `s<3`.

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
input_tbl[, {
     tmp <- unlist(str_extract_all(b, "[A-Za-z]+:[A-Za-z]+|\\d+"))
       list(b=tmp[c(TRUE, FALSE)], s=tmp[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
     }, by = .(a,c)][s<3]
#    a c      b s
#1: AA 1 ha:llo 1
#2: AA 1 wor:ld 2
```

---

Or if we are using `strsplit/tstrsplit`, grouped by 'a', 'c', we remove the curly brackets and quotes (`[{}]"`) with `gsub`, split by `,` (`strsplit`), `unlist` the output, and then use `tstrsplit` to split by `:` that is followed by a number.  The subset part is similar as above.

```
res <- input_tbl[, tstrsplit(unlist(strsplit(gsub('[{}"]', '', 
        b), ',', fixed=TRUE)), ":(?=\\d)", perl=TRUE) ,.(a,c)][V2<3]
setnames(res, 3:4, c("b", "s"))
res
#    a c      b s
#1: AA 1 ha:llo 1
#2: AA 1 wor:ld 2
```

#### Update

For the updated dataset, we can do the `tstrsplit` on the last delimiter (`:`)

```
res1 <- input2_tbl[, tstrsplit(unlist(strsplit(gsub('[{}"]', '', 
   b),',', fixed=TRUE)), ":(?=[^:]+$)", perl=TRUE) ,
         by = .(a, c)][V2 < 3]
setnames(res1, 3:4, c("b", "s"))
res1
#     a c                 b s
# 1: AA 1 99:1d:3u:7y:89:67 1
# 2: AA 1 99:1D:34:YY:T6:Y6 2
```

Comment: Hi @akrun Thank you very much! these are very elegant, just a small question though - what if the key might also contain numbers?

Comment: @shizik Thanks for the feedback.  What do you mean by the 'key'.?  Please show an example (by updating your post) so that it is clear.

Comment: Thank you, @akrun. I did so

Comment: @this worked perfectly. tnx! only when I wrap it as a function i get: Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list', any idea why? and of course Ill accept.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems like you are working with a JSON object, why not use something that parses the JSON, for example, the "jsonlite" package?

With that, you can make a simple function, that looks like this:

```
myFun <- function(invec) {
  require(jsonlite)
  x <- fromJSON(invec)
  list(b = names(x), s = unlist(x))
}
```

Now, applied to your dataset, you would get:

```
input_tbl[, myFun(b), by = .(a, c)]
#     a c        b s
# 1: AA 1   ha:llo 1
# 2: AA 1   wor:ld 2
# 3: AA 1 doog:bye 3
```

And, for the subsetting:

```
input_tbl[, myFun(b), by = .(a, c)][s <= 2]
#     a c      b s
# 1: AA 1 ha:llo 1
# 2: AA 1 wor:ld 2
```

You can probably also even rewrite the `myFun` function to add a "threshold" argument that lets you subset within the function itself.